# Can I download images from Selenium WITHOUT another URL request?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using Python, and I'm trying to render web pages with Selenium and download all of their images. The method I've read about is to save the `src` attribute URL values and then submit another HTTP request, like so:

```
import urllib.request

url = driver.find_element_by_id("your-image-id").get_attribute("src")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "local-filename.jpg")
```

But this is really inefficient at scale, since I'd be submitting a ton of extra requests for images I already loaded (I tried benchmarking with this approach, and it was many times slower than Selenium's downloading and rendering, which was surprising)

I couldn't find a way of saving the images directly from Selenium, even though this seems like a pretty obvious feature they'd have. Is there a way of doing this? (I can switch away from Python if I absolutely need to.)

Comment: There is the browser's cache, but that gets complicated.  (filenames used are not very helpful and they are temporary files...)

Comment: another option would be to take screenshots of the elements... not ideal because it would limit the resolution to the screen's dpi.

Answer (score 1):

The trick a browser uses is to download images asynchronously. Like download them all at once, to save waiting for the webpage to respond.

If you could offload the actual downloading like here [Python - Example of urllib2 asynchronous / threaded request using HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808138/python-example-of-urllib2-asynchronous-threaded-request-using-https) it would surely go a LOT quicker.

And as said, reading out the browser cache is tricky. Implementatie might change with the next browser version